# Windows 7 crash while attempting to move files after closing

Tags: windows-7, crash

How to reproduce: say folder "project1' is a Visual Studio 2010 folder, which contains the whole solution. After done with updating the project, I close the solution, but not Visual Studio. Also close TortoiseHg client after commit the last change. So these 2 applications are not likely to lock any folder/file. Also, I've closed all related files in editor, so editor application won't lock any file.

Then I tried to copy the 'porject1' folder to another place (in different drive). This action causes my explorer crash, generating report, and close all explorer instances. The 'project1' folder didn't get copied to destination.

This situation also happens when I finished editing MS Excel spreadsheet. After closing it, cut and paste the file to another folder also causes explorer crash.

This is log from Reliability Monitor.

```
> Windows Explorer Problem: stopped
> working Description Faulting
> Application Path: 
> C:\Windows\explorer.exe
> 
> Problem signature Problem Event Name:
> BEX64 Application Name:   Explorer.EXE
> Application Version:    6.1.7601.17514
> Application Timestamp:  4ce7a144 Fault
> Module Name:  MSVCR80.dll Fault Module
> Version:   8.0.50727.4940 Fault Module
> Timestamp: 4ca2b4dd Exception Offset: 
> 000000000001df0d Exception Code:
> c000000d Exception Data:
> 0000000000000000 OS Version:
> 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48 Locale ID:  1033 Additional Information 1:   5e1d
> Additional Information 2:  
> 5e1d64e35e71b3f9a1bf3e209e6282fe
> Additional Information 3:   92cc
> Additional Information 4:  
> 92cc0a832a0ad8ac8f072256bf80ab54
> 
> Extra information about the problem
> Bucket ID:  1648840625
```

This restart is really annoying. How can I further troubleshooting this issue? In Windows XP, if file gets locked, explorer will just pop up an error message. Is there any way to set Win 7 to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall or disable Tortoise Overlays - that anoying icons that appears in Windows Explorer.

Also try downloading Process Explorer in www.sysinternals.com to see all running processes and to kill suspect ones.

Comment: I've disabled that thing. Actually, this crash thing is more related to cut/paste file to another directory. Usually I have to copy and paste. After a couple minutes, go back and delete the original one.